# Content Fetching from XML file

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing

I have a xml content as below

```
<tty>
  <xyz id="1">
    <yzx>ghs</yzx>
    <dfg>kli</dfg>
  </xyz>
  <xyz id="2">
    <yzx>sss</yzx>
    <dfg>ddd</dfg>
  </xyz>
 </tty>
```

I need to fetch the content of xyz also and when I try to do so I face an error stating

```
 var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "file.xml",false);
    xmlHttp.send();
    xmlDoc = xmlHttp.responseXML;
    var wee= xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("xyz");
for(var i=0; i<wee.length;i++){
        var name = wee[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var yzx = wee[i].childNodes[1].nodeValue;
        var dfg= wee[i].childNodes[2].nodeValue;
```

error is

```
Cannot read property childnode
```

My output should have like below

```
name  1
yzx   ghs
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using getElementsByTagName twice :)

Answer (score 1):

`wee` is already all of the `<xyz>` tags, and there are no more `<xyz>` tags below it. That means the `getElementsBbyTagName('xyz')` inside the for loop will return nothing.

You probably just want

```
for(var i = 0; i < wee.length; i++) {
    var name = wee[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue; // "yzx" node
}
```

instead.

Comment: so do `childNodes[1]` as well, then.

Comment: so it has to be like `wee[i].childnodes[1].nodevalue` and `wee[i].childnodes[1].nodevalue` and so on?

Comment: If so I get an error as `cannotread property nodevalue of undefined`

Comment: js is case sensitive. `nodevalue != nodeValue`

Comment: yes I get the same for `nodeValue` and `childNodes` Sorry for confusing

Comment: I have updated my question with demo output can you please check it once

Comment: you really need to READ my answer. You've simply replicated your ORIGINAL mistake.

Comment: I tried analyzing your answer but Iam unable to get `xyz id="1"` output as well

Comment: I tell you don't need the getElementsByTagName inside the for loop, and yet you stuff them in again anyways? **READ** the answer.

Comment: sorry for confusing again :( updated with the answer you gave me even after performing above action I receive same error and as I said I need contents of xyz as well the 1 which is being showed I need to fetch that one as well

Comment: sorry to disturb you but did you get a chance to see my updated question

Comment: there's only 2 nodes under each xyz, so it impossible for childNodes[2] to exist. there'd be only [0] and [1].

Comment: my requirement is as below `<Details name="Holiday - Independence Day">
<status>Holiday</status>
<start_time>2014-07-04T00:00:00</start_time>
<end_time>2014-07-04T23:59:00</end_time>
</Details>' I need Details Name also to be displayed that is the whole requirement about

Comment: look, you need to fix this yourself. now you're showing more xml which was never in your original question? You've been given the answer for your problem. now it's up to you to learn WHY you had a problem in the first place.